# Correct handling of last block of data in Java. Boolean tokens or outofbonds indexes?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a list of arrays containing (I)ndex, (C)ategory, (S)ubcategory, (V)alue.

I C S V
0 1 1 A
1 1 1 B
2 1 2 C
3 1 3 D
4 1 3 E
5 2 1 F
6 2 1 G
7 2 2 H
8 2 2 J

I need to process A*B, then C, then D*E. Then process A*B+C+D*E, repeat operation for 2 and so on. Finally write an output file with:

```
 AB+C+DE
 FG+HJ
```

Please, don't interpret`*` and `+` literaly as product and sum.

```
public void translate(List<String[]> raw) {

    int oldCategory = 0;
    int newCategory = 0;
    int oldSubCategory = 0;
    int newSubCategory = 0;        

    boolean keepWorking = true;     
    do {        
        oldCategory = newCategory;
        newCategory = getNewCategory(oldCategory, raw); //get end of category. Now it returns 5, then 9.            
         do {               
            oldSubCategory = newSubCategory;    
            newSubCategory = getNewSubCategory(oldSubCategory, raw);            
            List<String> products = doFirstOperation(raw, oldCategory, newCategory, oldSubCategory, newSubCategory); //A*B, D*E, etc.

            } while (newSubCategory< newCategory);              
            doSecondOperation(products); // compute "A*B+C+D*E" and append it to file

        }   while (newCategory < raw.size());           
    }
```

`getNewCategory(oldCategory, raw)` returns the index of the first element in the new category or array.size() if current category is the last one.
In current setup I am routingly set newSubCategory outside of the scope of Category. This is asking for an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException down the road. I could use tokens `boolean isLastCategory`, do while (!isLastCategory) and return newCategory as the index of last element in a given category, but this looks bulky.

What would be a good way to organize such code?

Comment: So does your code work currently, or are you getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception?

Comment: My question is on optimal design pattern for breaks tracking. It is not about a local bug. Apparently, "cascading report breaks" is a way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern is known in some places as "cascading report breaks".  Here's one possible approach, in pseudo-code:

```
curCat = null
curSub = null
while rec = read()
    if (rec.cat != curCat)
        if (curCat != null)
            endCat()
        startCat()
    else if (rec.sub != curSub)
        endSub()
        startSub()
    accumulate rec
end while
if (curCat != null)
    endCat()

function startCat()
    curCat = rec.cat
    initialize cat accumulator
    startSub()

function startSub()
    curSub = rec.sub
    initialize sub accumulator

function endSub()
    finalize subcategory

function endCat()
    endSub()
    finalize category
```

If you don't like the null-checks as being wasteful (they only apply at the start of the file) you can use the following alternative:

```
rec = read()
if (!EOF)   
    startCat() 
    while rec = read()
        if (rec.cat != curCat)
            endCat()
            startCat()
        else if (rec.sub != curSub)
            endSub()
            startSub()
        accumulate rec
    end while
    endCat()
```

Adjust as needed for OOP-ness and encapsulation.

BTW, this goes back to the 1960s and COBOL report writing programs, but is still a neat way to conceptualize the idea of nested breaks and accumulation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Java8, here is the approach to accomplish this

```
    List<Model> models = new ArrayList<>();
    models.add(new Model("0", "1", "1", "A"));
    models.add(new Model("1", "1", "1", "B"));
    models.add(new Model("2", "1", "2", "C"));
    models.add(new Model("3", "1", "3", "D"));
    models.add(new Model("4", "1", "3", "E"));
    models.add(new Model("5", "2", "1", "F"));
    models.add(new Model("6", "2", "1", "G"));
    models.add(new Model("7", "2", "2", "H"));
    models.add(new Model("8", "2", "2", "J"));

    Map<String, Map<String, List<Model>>> map = models.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Model::getCategory, groupingBy(Model::getSubCategory)));

    List<String> strings = map.values().stream()
            .map(submap -> submap.values().stream()
                    .map(list -> list.stream().map(Model::getValue).collect(joining("*"))).collect(joining("+")))
            .collect(toList());

    System.out.println(strings);
```

Output

```
[A*B+C+D*E, F*G+H*J]
```